# How to access my own ogar server by using a custom domain?

Tags: node.js, centos, server

I followed the instruction and installed Ogar on my CentOS server successfully. But every time when my friends want to play on my server they have to use a google chrome and go to command lines and type 'connect("ws://agar.davidchen.com:443")'. It's not cool, because they think how the things work is you type a domain name (like 'agar.davidchen.com') then you can play the game, just like typing 'agar.io'. Is there any solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Use a web server to proxy the socket.io connection https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: can you give me more details? @Michelem

Answer (score 0):

You need to proxy the requests from HTTP to your socket connection via a web server like Nginx, so you can use http://agar.davidchen.com to access your web socket.

Install Nginx (version >= 1.3), then configure your virtual host with something like this:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    # This is where your web socket runs
    server 127.0.0.1:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name agar.davidchen.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/